# Troubles running LAStools on QGIS 3.28 Firenze. MAC, operational system MacOS 12.4

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, lastools

I ran into an issue of running the LAStools on QGIS. As it states in the subject, I have 3.28 Firenze version of QGIS, and it's operating on MacOS12.4

Every time I tried to run LASview, I get this message:

LAStools command line
/Applications/wine /Users/jeremywitek/Desktop/LAStools/bin/lasview -i "/Users/jeremywitek/Desktop/terra_las/cloud_merged.copc.laz" -points 5000000
LAStools console output
/bin/sh: /Applications/wine: No such file or directory

I did some research and I found out I need to install wine. I did, but now I am stuck trying to figure out how to set it up correctly so it works.

Under Processig-> options -> Providers -> LAStools
I have activated box checked,
under Lastools folder I have correct folder selected. it states as follows:
/Users/jeremywitek/Desktop/LAStools

I am unsure what should I put under Wine folder.
And also, not even sure if that's the cause of the problem...

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to download the LAStools Zip file.
https://downloads.rapidlasso.de/LAStools.zip
And extract the zip folder to C:/LAStools
And then install the QGIS plugin.

If you use the MacOS, download the Wine.
https://wiki.winehq.org/Download And put it into the /usr/bin
And set the wine directory in QGIS.
Regard.